# Error while creating middleware in Django to authenticate a user from different microservice

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-middleware, pyjwt

**Building Microservices With Django and pyJWT**

Let me explain this in summarised manor, maybe someone can help me out been at this for too long

I have three microservices i.e.

1. Authentication : Which creates the User and makes the token for a user using RS256 algorithm
2. Student : which is basically a user type that needs to be verified using JWT
3. Investor : which is also a user type that needs to be verified using JWT

[I have tried to make a generic create token function in authentication service something like]

```
data = {"id": user.uuid.hex, "type": user.user_type}
encoded = jwt.encode(data, private_key, algorithm="RS256")
return encoded
```

It is generating a correct token i have verified using JWT.io

In my student service i have created a middleware something like this

```
class JWTAuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    
    #Simple  JWT token based authentication.

    #Clients should authenticate by passing the token key in the "Authorization"
    #HTTP header, prepended with the string "Bearer ".  For example:

    #    Authorization: Bearer <UNIQUE_TOKEN>
   

    keyword = "Bearer"

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        auth = request.META.get("AUTHORIZATION", None)

        splitted = auth.split() if auth else []

        if len(splitted) == 2 and splitted[0] == self.keyword:
            if not splitted or splitted[0].lower() != self.keyword.lower().encode():
                return None
            if len(splitted) == 0:
                msg = _("Invalid token header. No credentials provided.")
                raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)
            elif len(splitted) > 2:
                msg = _("Invalid token header. Token string should not contain spaces.")
                raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

            user = get_user(request)

            decoded = verify_token(auth)
            try:
                student = Student.objects.get(user_id=decoded.get("id"))
            except Student.DoesNotExist:
                student = Student.objects.update(user_id=decoded.get("id"))

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

My verify_token function looks like

```
def verify_token(token):
decoded = jwt.decode(token, JWT_AUTH["PUBLIC_KEY"], algorithms=["RS256"])
return decoded
```

I have also added my middleware in my settings just below authentication middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "config.middleware.authentication.JWTAuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]
```

I am just not able to decode my token and assign the payload to respective user type, Can someone help me out where i am going wrong? I have also tried using Authentication backend something like this, it doesn't works, have implemented *simple_jwt_djangorestframework* package but it doesn't decode my payload on student service and says invalid token so i don't want to add it for increasing unnecessary code too.

My viewset looks like this

```
class StudentViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = Student.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
    lookup_field = "uuid"
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

My error is always saying when i am using isAuthenticated as permission class

```
"message": "Authentication credentials were not provided.",
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe validating raw token should work :

```
decoded = verify_token(splitted[1])
```

Actually you don't have to implement it. There is [simple jwt package](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#installation) for it. Install the package by its documentation and if it wouldn't work provide errors to help you.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. It's still saying authentication credentials not provided, do i need to use rest framework's permission class or just need a way to implement in my middleware on;y?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question myself for future references

```
class JWTAuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    
    #Simple  JWT token based authentication.

    #Clients should authenticate by passing the token key in the "Authorization"
    #HTTP header, prepended with the string "Bearer ".  For example:

    #    Authorization: Bearer <UNIQUE_TOKEN>
   

    keyword = "Bearer"

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        auth = request.META.get("AUTHORIZATION", None)

        splitted = auth.split() if auth else []

        if len(splitted) == 2 and splitted[0] == self.keyword:
            if not splitted or splitted[0].lower() != self.keyword.lower().encode():
                return None
            if len(splitted) == 0:
                msg = _("Invalid token header. No credentials provided.")
                return JsonResponse(data=msg, status=403, safe=False)
            elif len(splitted) > 2:
                msg = _("Invalid token header. Token string should not contain spaces.")
                return JsonResponse(data=msg, status=403, safe=False)

            user = get_user(request)

            decoded = verify_token(auth)
            try:
                student = Student.objects.get(user_id=decoded.get("id"))
                return self.get_response(request)
            except Student.DoesNotExist:
                msg = _("Invalid User Not found")
                return JsonResponse(data=msg, status=403, safe=False)
```

couple of things that i was doing wrong was not passing a response when i found a student that's why middleware was not bypassed at that time, also exceptions cannot be used at middleware level middleware only returns HTTPResponses, thus i thought of using JsonResponse.